# When I try to upload an image to my chat website it doesn't save the variable

Tags: php

I have a simple chat website, and I'm trying to add a profile-picture feature. This is my code:

```
<?php
function loginForm(){
echo
'<div id="loginform">
<p>Please enter your name to continue!</p>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Display Name: </label>
  <input style="font-family: Sans-serif;" type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <label for="name">Profile picture: </label>
  <input style="font-family: Sans-serif;" type="text" name="pfp" id="name" />
  <input style="font-family: Sans-serif;" type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
</form>
</div>
<center><h2>Upload profile picture: </h2><br><?php error_reporting(0); ?> <?php $msg = "";    if (isset($_POST[\'uploadfile\'])) { $filename = $_FILES["choosefile"]["name"]; $tempname = $_FILES["choosefile"]["tmp_name"]; $folder = "image/".$filename; $_SESSION[\'pfp\'] = $folder; $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Image_upload"); $sql = "INSERT INTO image (filename) VALUES (\'$filename\')"; ($db, $sql);  if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder)) { $msg = "Image uploaded successfully"; }else{ $msg = "Failed to upload image"; } } $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM image"); ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Image Upload in PHP</title> <! link the css file to style the form > <style type="text/css"> #wrapper{ width: 50%; margin: 20px auto; } form{ width: 50%; margin: 20px auto; } form div{ margin-top: 5px; } img{ float: left; margin: 5px; width: 280px; height: 120px; } #img_div{ width: 70%; padding: 5px; margin: 15px auto; border: 1px solid #dad7d7; } #img_div:after{ content: ""; display: block; clear: both; } button, input, span { background: #41d18e; border: none; color: white; padding: 4px 10px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 20px; } </style> </head> <body> <div id="wrapper"> <! specify the encoding type of the form using the enctype attribute > <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="file" name="choosefile" value="" /> <div> <button type="submit" name="uploadfile">Use as new profile pic</button> </div> </form> </div></center>';
}
?>
<div id="menu">
    <?php echo "<img style=\"width: 20px; border-radius: 9999px;\" src=".$_SESSION['pfp'].">"; ?>
    <p class="welcome">&nbsp;Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
    <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Rename</a></p>
</div>
```

For some reason <p class="welcome"></p> works perfectly fine, but the image just doesn't show. I looked in my **image** folder but could not find the image that I uploaded earlier.

Thanks for all the support.

Comment: If the image isn't there then the problem is more likely to be with the code which uploads it, surely? Was the image ever there, did the upload ever succeed?

Comment: Check your server logs for errors?

Comment: Does that `img` tag appear in the outputted HTML or is it completely absent? If it does appear in the outputted email, does the `src` have a value? If it does have a value, does that path exist and point to an image file? If it does, are there any errors in your php log like 'not authorized' or similar?

Comment: This maybe the issue: Change `src=".$_SESSION['pfp'].">";` to `src=\"".$_SESSION['pfp']."\">";` so the image link/location is properly surrounded in quotes in the outputted html.

Comment: @ADyson the page just reloads when I upload my file and press "Use as new profile pic." I check the image folder, and there is nothing there.

Comment: @JNevill the img tag appears, and so does the src attribute. The src="".

Comment: Suggesting there is nothing in `$_SESSION['pfp']`

Comment: @JNevill I added <?php $user = $_SESSION['name']; 
    $_SESSION['pfp'] = $folder; ?> directly above <div id="menu"> but it does the same thing.

Comment: Does `$folder` have a value though? What does `<?php echo $folder ?>` spit out?

Comment: If the upload is going wrong then that needs fixing, so you need to show us that code (and the results of your attempts to debug it so far) instead of this code - trying to show an image which doesn't exist is futile.

Comment: @JNevill when I try that, I get ""

Comment: @ADyson the code that uploads the file is: <?php error_reporting(0); ?> <?php $msg = ""; if (isset($_POST[\'uploadfile\'])) { $filename = $_FILES["choosefile"]["name"]; $tempname = $_FILES["choosefile"]["tmp_name"]; $folder = "image/".$filename; $_SESSION[\'pfp\'] = $folder; $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Image_upload"); $sql = "INSERT INTO image (filename) VALUES (\'$filename\')"; ($db, $sql); if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder)) { $msg = "Image uploaded successfully"; }else{ $msg = "Failed to upload image"; } } $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM image"); ?> –

Comment: Hi. As you can see, it's quite hard to read the code when it's placed in the comments like this. Stackoverflow isn't like a standard discussion forum (see the [tour] for more info). Your question has an "edit" button under it, which you can use to improve the main question, then the information is visible, all in one place, and can be formatted properly. To allow us to consider your code fully, please edit your question and place it there. [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) may be useful to read as well. Thankyou.

Comment: Also you need to explain the results when you run that code - e.g. do you get the "Failed to upload image" message, or what?

Comment: First of all where is the "choosefile" named file input? And you forgot the enctype attribute in your form tag <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> if you don't add enctype attribute $_FILES global returns nothing...

Comment: Could you place break code like this into multiple lines when posting it here, so that we don't have to scroll a mile sideways.

Answer (score 0):

replace the line and see

```
"<img style="width:20px;",src=<?php echo $_SESSION['pfp'];?>"
```

his maybe the issue: Change  so the image link/location is properly surrounded in quotes in the outputted html.